How to remove the slash and get output as mentioned from the date in oracle apex sql
I need to remove the slash from the date , i am using below query to get the Output.
SELECT 'AB-'||a.store_no||'-'||a.created_date
FROM ORDER_STORE a;
The output coming as: AB-285485-08/15/2024
I need output as    : AB-285485-15AUG2024
Please modify the query above to get the required output as below
I need output as    : AB-285485-15AUG2024
Need to Remove the slash and also i need to change date 08/15/2024 to 15AUG2024

Assuming created_date is of date type:
SELECT 'AB-'||a.store_no||'-'|| replace(to_char(a.created_date,'DD/MON/YYYY'),'/','') FROM ORDER_STORE a;

Will result as:
AB-285485-15AUG2024


The "replace" function is not needed. Just use a format mask without the forward slash. to_char(a.created_date,'DDMONYYYY') works just fine.
